# Properly extracting from an array

Tags: powershell, csv, array

I have a CSV with one column, numbers formatted as `111-0000`, that I'm reading in to process one at a time. I'm trying to import the column of information from the CSV, but I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to extract it from the array once it's read in from the CSV.

This is what the CSV looks like:

Project
111-0000
112-0000

What I want to get out of the file is a variable that returns each project number. So far, all I'm able to get returned is:

```
@{Project=111-0000}
```

Currently, all I have is the initial `ForEach` statement reading the lines out of the CSV file.

```
$CSV=Import-Csv "C:\ProjectList.csv"
ForEach ($Entry in $CSV)
```

At this point, inserting

```
Write-Host $Entry
```

returns the following information:

@{Project=110-0000}
@{Project=111-0000}
@{Project=112-0000}
@{Project=113-0000}

What I want at this point is to extract the number out of that and use it later on in the script, where I'm doing other process against that project. The final string I want process each time the ForEach hits an entry looks like this:

C:\111-0000

I'll process this path then start over, pulling in the next project in the list, and processing it, on down the list. But I can't get the right code to keep it from coming out in the end as:

C:\@{Project=111-0000}

I've tried using another ForEach inside the first ForEach to extract the number out of the code and pass it on, this is where I'm getting stuck:

```
$lvCSV = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
ForEach ($Col in ($lvCSV.Columns )| ?{$_.Text -ne "Project"}){
$ProjectNumber = $Col.Text
```

I know that I need to process `$Entry` more, but I can't find/figure the right process to do so. Can you help guide me in the right direction?

Code Snippet:

```
$CSV=Import-Csv "C:\ProjectList.csv"

ForEach ($Entry in $CSV){

$lvCSV = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView #Defined at script start
ForEach ($Col in ($lvCSV.Columns )| ?{$_.Text -ne "Project"}){
$ProjectNumber = $Col.Text
```

Comment: Why have you applied the [microsoft-excel] tag? Are you using Excel somewhere in this process?

Comment: Please clarify what you are attempting. Your tags imply that you are trying to create an Excel file from a CSV file, using PowerShell. That seems the wrong way to import CSV files into Excel.

Comment: We will probably need to see more code. For instance what does $CSV hold? How is it populated? An example of the CSV itself would help too. Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: Also, if you're using PowerShell to read a CSV file into a PowerShell array, what's wrong with `$project = Import-Csv "project.csv"` ?

Comment: Post updated to hopefully make more sense and correctly portray my intent.

Comment: So, the Foreach($Col in ($lvCSV.Columns) loop is inside the Foreach($Entry in $CS) loop? How are you trying to output $entry? What does the CSV look like?

Comment: Yes, the loop is inside the first loop. $Entry is being aquired directly from the first loop where it's read from the CSV. Since it's a single column, I'm trying to read the info in a column list view. $Entry comes out as an array variable, I'm trying to output a subset of $Entry into the $ProjectNumber variable. The CSV example is the first item in the post, Cell A1 is the text 'Project' and cells A2-Ax are numbers in the 111-0000 format.

Comment: Well, $Col is a column from $lvCSV.Columns and doesn't directly have anything to do with $Entry or the contents of the CSV.

Comment: Hence my problem. What's the proper way to extract 111-0000 out of @{Project=111-0000} that's stored in the $Entry variable? It should be fairly simple but I just can't grasp how to do it.

Comment: My point is that you haven't explained any way that you are currently, in your actual code, trying to access $Entry at all. It is hard to tell you what you are doing wrong with that variable when you apparently never actually use that variable for anything. $Entry.Project should get what you need.

Comment: Ah, first off, my apologies. I been staring at this too long and obviously tried to make it more complicated than it needed to be. The $Col of the ForEach should have been $Entry. I started with $Col since it was column data i was trying to read and forgot to change it here. Since it was a column, I was trying to use the list view to list each entry one by one out of the CSV and capture the string that way. It never dawned on me that $Entry.Project would spit out each entry in turn. Thank you EBGreen.